# How can I apply this to my theme's functions.php file, rather than a core WordPress file?

Tags: wordpress

I need to apply a class to the post archive links that are output by WordPress' `get_archive_links` function. I can accomplish this by modifying `/wp-includes/general-template.php (line 842)`, from this:

```
$link_html = "\t<li>$before<a href='$url' title='$title_text'>$text</a>$after</li>\n";
```

to this:

```
$link_html = "\t<li>$before<a class='hello' href='$url' title='$title_text'>$text</a>$after</li>\n";
```

I'm pretty sure I need to add some sort of filter in my theme's functions.php to accomplish this the smart way, without modifying a core file, I just don't know how. Any guidance would be awesome.

EDIT: Here is the entire, unmodified function from general-template.php:

```
function get_archives_link($url, $text, $format = 'html', $before = '', $after = '') {
$text = wptexturize($text);
$title_text = esc_attr($text);
$url = esc_url($url);

if ('link' == $format)
    $link_html = "\t<link rel='archives' title='$title_text' href='$url' />\n";
elseif ('option' == $format)
    $link_html = "\t<option value='$url'>$before $text $after</option>\n";
elseif ('html' == $format)
    $link_html = "\t<li>$before<a href='$url' title='$title_text'>$text</a>$after</li>\n";
else // custom
    $link_html = "\t$before<a href='$url' title='$title_text'>$text</a>$after\n";

$link_html = apply_filters( 'get_archives_link', $link_html );

return $link_html;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to do this, thanks to [this page](http://diythemes.com/thesis/rtfm/archives-widget-nofollow/).

Just throw this in `functions.php`:

```
// Filter to add nofollow attribute
function nofollow_archives($link_html) {
return str_replace('<a href=', '<a rel="nofollow" href=',  $link_html);
}
```

Then call the new function wherever you'd like:

```
<?php add_filter('get_archives_link', 'nofollow_archives'); ?>
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
```

The example is obviously showing how to add a nofollow rel tag, but you can easily modify it to add a link class or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this?

```
function new_get_archives_link ( $link_html ) {
   if ('html' == $format) {
         $link_html = "\t<li>$before<a class='hello' href='$url' title='$title_text'>$text</a>$after</li>\n";
      }
      return $link_html;
   }
add_filter("get_archives_link", "new_get_archives_link");
```

copy this into your functions.php and you shouldnt have to edit core files.

untested..

Comment: Hi Marty, thank you for the answer. That looks like it should work but unfortunately it doesn't.